# Problem recreating black hole iridesium

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying my hardest to follow this Iridesium tutorial, but every time I try to render it, it doesn't render the Emission Color nodes.

[Tutorial The Accretion Disk creation 5:03](https://youtu.be/5naMFeWTBeY?t=303)

[The accretion disc material](https://youtu.be/5naMFeWTBeY?t=303) he later posted it in another video

[.blend file](https://pasteall.org/media/d/7/d7f325710d67f3251febb24660d4fba6.blend)